# Can a user removed from smart group manually be added back automatically if criteria is satisfied?

Tags: smartgroups, scheduled-reminders

I have a requirement,
 where I need to Limit Scheduled Reminders to Only Members with Active and Grace Status(which is a smart group) 
But 
If I remove a user manually from 
Member with Active And Grace Status Group,
will he stop getting Scheduled Reminder even though
 he/she is an Active Member or Grace Status Member, also is there a possibility when he pays again for membership, will smart group add him back or once removed from smart group manually, he/she will not be added at all

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A person once removed(not deleted) from smart group won't be added again back automatically if the contact's updates his/her information or membership. So schedule reminder will exclude the contacts that are removed from smart group.

Answer (score 3):

I would implement this using two smart groups:

**Smart Group A**

- Consists of members with Active/Grace status.
- Cannot have members who are in Group B.

**Smart Group B**

- Members manually added to designate that they shouldn't be in Group A.
- Remove members of group B automatically with CiviRules when they pay membership renewal to allow them to be automatically added to Group A again.

I've tested a similar group membership workflow on a testbed running D7.59 and CiviCRM 5.1.2 and it worked in my, admittedly, limited testing.

**Edit to address feedback from Jon G**

*This may run into performance issues for which there is no workaround at present due to the use of unindexed join due to the combination of smart groups and other smart groups / non-smart groups*

*These performance issues should only really be evident when regenerating the smart group membership.*

Comment: This broadly works - but "Smart groups made up of other smart groups AND non-smart groups" comes up against some performance issues (unindexed joins) that unfortunately there's no current workaround for.

Comment: I absolutely agree that this is **not** going to be performant but it's the only way I could get this working as a mostly automated process which seemed to be the requirement.

Comment: @JonG-MegaphoneTech I've made an edit to incorporate your feedback - I'd appreciate your thoughts.