# Create a smart group that excludes

Tags: smartgroups

Is there a way to have more exclude options in smart groups? The only exclude I see is from contact preferences. I would like to create a smart group for donors that live in CA BUT do not live in Bakersfield, CA.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Search Builder (**Search menu » Search Builder**) gives exclusion options on pretty much any field.  See the attached screenshot.  You would of course have to add additional criteria relating to who constitutes a donor.[image]

Comment: When I create a smart group from this search, will future donors who fit this search criteria be added to the smart group?

Comment: Yup!  That's the nature of smart groups.

Answer (score 1):

You can use custom search 'Include / Exclude Search' (CiviCRM >> Search >> Custom Searches >> Include / Exclude Search)

1. Create a smart group of donor who stay in CA
2. Create a smart group of donor who stay in Bakersfield, CA
3. Use Include / Exclude Search, to search contact in group #1 and exclude from #2

Thanks

Pradeep

Comment: Is the Include/Exclude Search a part of the Smart Group settings? Also, I had found this post that discouraged a Smart Group that excludes a list from another Smart Group https://civicrm.stackexchange.com/questions/25004/can-a-user-removed-from-smart-group-manually-be-added-back-automatically-if-crit/25006#25006

Comment: There can be performance issue if you building smart group from combination of more than 3-4 smart groups. I you have enough group rebuild cache time set that it shouldn't be a problem.